# D3 canvas force directed layout bottom issue

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to contain/bound the nodes while dragging within the layout.
I tried to modify the example [Force Dragging III Canvas](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/ad70335eeef6d167bc36fd3c04378048)  and added the following code :

```
function dragstarted() {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d3.event.subject.fx = Math.max(10, Math.min(width - 10, d3.event.subject.x)) ;
  d3.event.subject.fy = Math.max(10, Math.min(width - 10, d3.event.subject.y)) ;
}

function dragged() {
  d3.event.subject.fx = Math.max(10, Math.min(width - 10, d3.event.x));
  d3.event.subject.fy = Math.max(10, Math.min(width - 10, d3.event.y));
}
```

Though I am able to constrain the movement to the top, left and right direction but seems like there is something wrong with the bottom dragging; it does not stop after reaching the rectangle bottom. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you just made a mistake by using the `width` variable for the x axis and for the y axis. It should be OK by using your `height` variable for the y axis like that:

```
function dragstarted() {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d3.event.subject.fx = Math.max(10, Math.min(width - 10, d3.event.subject.x)) ;
  d3.event.subject.fy = Math.max(10, Math.min(height - 10, d3.event.subject.y)) ;
}

function dragged() {
  d3.event.subject.fx = Math.max(10, Math.min(width - 10, d3.event.x));
  d3.event.subject.fy = Math.max(10, Math.min(height - 10, d3.event.y));
}
```